# FireStore avoid manual mapping .setData()

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question, is it possible to avoid manual mapping using the setData() method of FireStore and to pass a complete object instead?

e.g.:

```
func startTimeTracking(timeTracking: TimeTracking) {
    db.collection("timetracking").document().setData(["productionId" : timeTracking.productionId, "employeeId" : timeTracking.employeeId, "taskType" : timeTracking.taskType, "status" : timeTracking.status, "timestampStart" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), "timestampStop" : nil])
}
```

Pseudo:

```
func startTimeTracking(timeTracking: TimeTracking) {
    db.collection("timetracking").document().setData(timeTracking)
}
```

Thanks for your support.

Best

Comment: Have you tried your assumption? What is the result?

Comment: Yes, not working: Cannot convert value of type 'TimeTracking' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'. I probably would need to convert the object to a dictionary, but is there a more clever way? The reason is i would like not to hardcode mappings.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: thanks a lot. Why is it not mentioned in the official documentation? For .updateData() it doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: Let's see if @PeterFriese can answer those questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extend some aspect of Firestore to give you this functionality. `setData()` is a `DocumentReference` method, so you could extend `DocumentReference`.

```
extension DocumentReference {
    func setData(with object: TimeTracking) {
        self.setData([
            "productionId": object.productionId,
            "employeeId": object.employeeId
        ])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct TimeTracking {
    let productionId: String
    let employeeId: String
}

let tt = TimeTracking(productionId: "abc", employeeId: "xyz")

Firestore.firestore().collection("timetracking").document().setData(with: tt)
```

This extension obviously only handles a single type and does not handle all of the overloads of `setData()`, which includes additional parameters and a completion handler. But accounting for those is easy, if you need them.